# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object. Trying to add product to a basket

Tags: php, sql

I'm making an online shop where a user can order a shoe, this is then passed to the basket, and the user can then checkout. At the moment I am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object,  on this line '$row = $query->fetch_assoc();' in the checkoutAction.php file.

checkoutAction.php

```
     <?php


      include "checkout.php";

      $checkout = new Checkout;

      include "db.php";



    $id = $_REQUEST['equipmentID'];

    $query = $conn->query("Select * from equipment Where equipmentID = ".$id);
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $data = array('id' => $row['equipmentID'], 'name' => $row['productname'], 'price' => $row['purchaseprice'], qty=> '1');

    $addProduct = $checkout->addToBasket($data);
    $redirect = $addToBasket?'viewBasket.php':'goretex.php';
    header($redirect);


   }
```

checkout.php

```
 <?php 

  session_start(); 

  class Checkout {

public function addToBasket($product = array())
{
        $product['quantity'] = (float) $product['quantity'];
        $product['purchaseprice'] = (float) $product['purchaseprice'];
        $equipmentid = md5($product['equipmentID']);


        if($this->saveCheckout())
        {
            return isset($equipmentid) ? $equipmentid : TRUE;

        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }


}
```

Html/Front End

```
   div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" id="size" onclick        ="changeColor()"class="btn btn-warning">7</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">8</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">9</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">10</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">11</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">12</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="basketAction.php?action=addToBasket&equipmentID=<?php echo $row["equipmentID"]; ?> class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add to Basket</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: That's because your query has failed to execute. Try this, `... Where equipmentID = '". $id . "'");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably because your `$conn->query(...)` statement return a FALSE. Check the `mysqli::query` documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). It's stated that on failure this method will return FALSE, that's why the `$query->fetch_assoc()` throws an error.

Update your code to capture this failure and display the error message, so you can further debug it.

```
$query = $conn->query("Select * from equipment Where equipmentID = ".$id);

// If query return FALSE, there's an error.
if (! $query) {
    throw new \Exception("Database errror: {$conn->error}");
}

$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using mysqli: you need to check the result of `$conn->query(...)` it may return `false` if the query failed (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

And please consider using prepared statements, instead of putting the `equipmentId` directly into the SQL, to prevent SQL injection.